# require_once strange behavior. refreshes the page 4 times

Tags: php

i had a insert query whenever the page loads. But i see the insert query being executed 4 times on each page visit.

I tested and found that the require_once statement in causing this. i am getting the file path & name in variable and do the following. which re produce the problem.

But if i hardcode the require_once("path/file.php") it works; the variable have the same value when i echo it.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['testt']))
    $_SESSION['testt'] = 0;

$_SESSION['testt']++;

$va = $oReq->getIncludeFile();

require_once($va);
// if i write session before this line, session increments 4 times.
// But after this line session increment 1 times. I'm confused here.
// But if i hardcode the require statement with file path & name,
// session increments 1 time. Why?

echo "session count: ".$_SESSION['testt']; //outputs 4
```

It Seems the page reloads 4 times if used require_once statement with file path in variable.

**Edit:**

```
function getIncludeFile($sSuffix='php')
{
    // returns client/index.php
    return $this->_sPart.'/'.$this->_sSect.'.'.$sSuffix;
}
```

Please guide.

Comment: What kind of script do you `require_once`? It seems it is the one causing the trouble.

Comment: show this method- getIncludeFile()

Comment: i have a client/index.php, when i do require_once("client/index.php") it works, but when i do require_once($va) $va have same string when i echo. it produce the behavior